# How to trigger the same branch Gitlab pipeline from other pipeline file on certain stage(not downstream pipeline)?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I need to start the same pipeline parallel and independent but with other runners. For these purposes i have another pipeline file `.gitlab-ci-test.yml`.
I have the pipeline which has different stages:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - dockerize
  - integration-test
```

The Problem.
On the stage `dockerize` I will start the same branch but with another pipeline `.gitlab-ci-test.yml`. This pipeline file is in the same branch.
I can use trigger API, but there are no parameters to set `.gitlab-ci-test.yml` as pipeline file.

I hope, that my problem is understandable.

Thanks for the help.